# Utility method to check if only one element is not null

Tags: java

Are there utility methods to do this check in one call?

```
object1 == null && object2 == null
            || object1 != null && object2 != null
```

Comment: You can just write that method yourself. That would be far easier than importing a library or anything similar.

Comment: your code contradicts the question. your code checks if both null or both not null. which one is it?

Comment: `return (object1 == null) == (object2 == null);` No need to make it more complicated than that. Note that your title and your sample code do two different checks. For the in-title one replace the `==` in the midle with a `!=`.

Comment: I updated the title. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So to rephrase: you want to check that **exactly** one of the two values is non-null (and thus the other one is `null`), right?

Comment: Yes this is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create your own method and place it somewhere, maybe a `Util` class or something of that sort.

Please note that this code does what the title of your question is asking for, not what the code in your question's text does.

```
public static boolean isOnlyOneNotNull(Object o1, Object o2) {
   return o1==null&&o2!=null || o1!=null&&o2==null;
}
```